# In which cases can __declspec( align( # ) ) not work?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, memory-alignment

I have a class:

```
class CMatrix4f
{
public:
    CMatrix4f();

public:
     __declspec(align(16)) float m[16];
};
```

This class implements matrix operations with SSE, so `m` *must* be aligned for it to work. And it works most of the time, but sometimes I get segfault when executing SSE instructions like `_mm_load_ps` because `m` is not 16-bytes aligned. So far I can't understand in which cases it happens.

When I do `CMatrix4f * dynamicMatrix = new CMatrix4f();`, is `dynamicMatrix.m` guaranteed to be aligned?

If I have a class:

```
class MatrixWrapper {
public:
   MatrixWrapper();

   CMatrix4f _matrix;
};
```

And then do:

```
MatrixWrapper * dynamicMatrixWrapper = new MatrixWrapper();
```

Is `dynamicMatrixWrapper._matrix.m` guaranteed to be aligned?

I've read MSDN article on alignment, but it is unclear whether it works for dynamic allocation.

Comment: No, this won't work, notorious problem in C++.  The compiler knows the alignment requirement for the object but just doesn't have any way to pass that knowledge on to the allocator.  Fixing this in the language spec is a major breaking change.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

since `__declspec(align(#))` is a compilation directive, creating the `MatrixWrapper` object with the new operator can result in unaligned memory on the heap. You may consider using  [_aligned_malloc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6.aspx) and allocate memory dynamically, for example in the constructor, and then free it using `_aligned_free` in the destructor, by the way mixing static and dynamic allocation of object makes things more difficult.

Comment: Though MS says # can be up to 8192 practically I get error for # > 128. Have you seen it? this is MS Documentation - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83ythb65.aspx.